# How to insert line break at the end of specific line of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have UITextView with 10 lines and now I'm trying to insert line break at the end of 5th line. How is it possible?

Comment: Create an array by separating text with the line break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Split the text into lines with `components(separatedBy: .newlines)`
- Get the 5th line (at index 4!)
- Get the range of the line in the text with `range(of:)`
- Insert the line break at the `upperBound` index of the range.

Comment: Actually there is one whole text which looks like as 10 lines on simulator and when I'm trying to get components(separatedBy: .newlines) it only gets one whole text.

Comment: If there are no *physical* lines how do you know what the 5th line is? There is no way unless you know the partial string where the line break is supposed to be inserted.

Comment: Let's assume that 5th line is 5th line shown on simulator, is there a way to insert line break on that line without knowing partial string?

Comment: *On simulator* what? iPhone SE, 11 max, iPad something? No, you need to be able to identify the insertion location independent of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

here is :

```
 let textview = UITextView()
        textview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        textview.text = "djhgiruior seitii iuuiuy  yyt  yt tr dtre d grf hth yghj  jh u hu khku yi  hhhhh\nuiytuftftyftyfytf"
        textview.backgroundColor = .green
        self.view.addSubview(textview)
```

It will give new line after `'\n'` . So use this